# PHP Multiple Object Dereference

Tags: php

How can I do multiple levels of de-referencing? For instance, in C#, we can keep appending a '.' to access the next objects properties: `string s, s.ToString(), s.ToString().ToUpper()`. With PHP, I get to around `$this->someobject`, but `$this->someobject->somethingelse` does not appear to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, actually, it does work in PHP, too. So may we see a code sample?

Comment: It works, if your `someobject` is actually an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using `PHP5+`, and `$this->someobject` returns an object with a property called `somethingelse`; it should work.

Similarly, this also works

```
class Example
{
    public function foo()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
        return $this; // returning an object (self)
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        echo ' World';
        return $this;
    }
}

$example = new Example;
$example->foo()->bar(); // Hello World
$example->foo()->foo()->foo()->bar()->foo(); // HelloHelloHello WorldHello
```

### Edit:

Just as a further note, you don't have to return `self`. Any object will suffice.

```
class Example1
{
    public function __construct(Example2 $example2)
    {
        $this->example2 = $example2;
        $this->example2->setExample1($this);
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
        return $this->example2;
    }
}

class Example2
{
    public function setExample1(Example1 $example1)
    {
        $this->example1 = $example1;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        echo ' World';
        return $this->example1;
    }
}

$example = new Example1(new Example2());
$example->foo()->bar(); // Hello World
$example->foo()->bar()->foo()->bar(); // Hello WorldHello World
```

Comment: Fair enough. Silly question: Classes do count as Objects, correct?

Comment: An instance of a class is an object. A class accessed statically is not. So you could return an instance of any class you wanted to be able to then chain to a method in that class.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's dereference operator only works on Objects; and, unlike some other languages, only Objects are objects ;) Primitives don't have an implicit wrapper. So, if `$this->someobject` resolves to a non object, (like a `string`, `float`, `int` or `array`), you cannot chain the dereference operator any further.

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax correct, but only for nested objects.  Frequently, an object property might be of the array type, so you would need to access it accordingly: `$this->somearray['somekey'];`

If you're looking to create a fluent interface to allow for chaining, the object methods would need to `return $this;` in order to facilitate that.

Classes can also be accessed with the `::` (scope resolution operator) without being instantiated, but that's a little outside of the scope of the question.

Hope that helps!